# Expanding menu on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a basic menu looking something like this.

```
<ul id="menu">
<li id="auctions">Auctions</li>
<li class="submenu">Submenu 1</li>
<li class="submenu">Submenu 2</li>
<li class="submenu">Submenu 3</li>
</ul>
```

I want the three submenus to be hidden until the text "Auctions" is clicked. Then they're supposed to appear, and become hidden again when "Auctions" is clicked a second time and so on. Ive tried something like this.

```
$(function() {
    $('#auctions').click(function() {        
        $('#menu').animate({'height': '200'});
        $('#submenu').animate({opacity : 'toggle'});
    }, function () {
        $('#menu').stop().animate({'height': '100'});
        $('#submenu').animate({opacity : 'toggle'});
    });
});
```

In all honesty I suck at jquery. How do I approach this?

Comment: Try this: http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: Firstly, submenu is a class not an id, so you need to use `.submenu` where you use `#submenu`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [jQuery's `.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/), also make sure `.submenu` is not visible:

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(function() {
    $('#auctions').click(function(){
      $('.submenu').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.submenu{display:none;}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/SLGdE/4/

Comment: Works like a charm, accepting answer in a few mins. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
$('#auctions').click(function(){
  $("#menu, .submenu").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Change `#submenu` to `.submenu`

Answer (score 0):

Your basic structure is fine, yet i wouldn't use `css()`. Use `slideToggle()` in stead:

```
$(function() {
    $('#auctions').click(function() {        
        $('.submenu').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: submenu should be a class instead of an id

Comment: @Schoffelman Indeed, didn't paided attention to his code when i copied it

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use this code :

```
    $(function() {
$('.submenu').hide();
   $('#auctions').click(function() {        
       //$('#menu').animate({'height': '200'});
       $('.submenu').toggle("slow");

});

});
```

apart from that you use `"#submenu"` and in your html its `class` you should use `".submenu"`