# onclick expand multiple menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make an `onclick` expand multiple menu in my website

Before I follow this thread: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226140/expanding-menu-on-click) with little bit modify I get:

```
<ul>
  <rg><li id="auctions">Menu</li></rg>
  <br></br>
  <lf>
    <li class="submenu">Left</li>
  </lf>
  <rg>
    <li class="submenu">Right</li>
  </rg>
</ul>
```

But it only shows a menu, then I create a duplicate like this:

```
<ul>
  <rg><li id="auctions">Menu</li></rg>
  <br></br>
  <lf>
    <li class="submenu">Left</li>
  </lf>
  <rg>
    <li class="submenu">Right</li>
  </rg>
</ul><ul>
  <rg><li id="auctions2">Menu</li></rg>
  <br></br>
  <lf>
    <li class="submenu2">Left</li>
  </lf>
  <rg>
    <li class="submenu2">Right</li>
  </rg>
</ul>
```

And JS and CSS like this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#auctions').click(function(){
      $('.submenu').slideToggle();
    });
});
$(function() {
    $('#auctions2').click(function(){
      $('.submenu2').slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>

<style>
  .submenu{display:none;}
  .submenu2{display:none;}
  rg {float:right}
  lf {float:left}
</style>
```

Its work but doesn't run `inline`. Then I use`ul {display:inline-block}`

Yes, the menu running `inline`, but it's broken and `float` doesn't work properly. Can it's fixed? or can I make multiple menu in same `<ul>`?

Comment: What are `<rg>` and `<lf>` elements? The only element that is valid as a direct child of a `<ul>` is an `<li>`. Why are you creating a menu that is not accessible to keyboard-only users?

Comment: rg is css for floating:right and lf is for floating:left

i dont kno to make it work for keyboard-only user

Answer (score 0):

make `rg` and `lf` as classes and change the html accordingly to get your desired style.

But I recommend, you should consider studying about `ul` and `li` [***tags and its properties***](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp) before using it

```js
$(function() {
  $('#auctions').click(function() {
    $('.submenu').slideToggle();
  });
});
$(function() {
  $('#auctions2').click(function() {
    $('.submenu2').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
li.main {
  width:100%;
  text-align:right;
}

.submenu {
  display: none;
}

.submenu2 {
  display: none;
}

.rg {
  float: right;
}

.lf {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li id="auctions" class="main rg">Menu</li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li class="submenu lf">Left</li>
          <li class="submenu rg">Right</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li id="auctions2" class="main rg">Menu</li>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li class="submenu2 lf">Left</li>
          <li class="submenu2 rg">Right</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! but still not inline. btw i've done it with another ways, then Case Closed.

Comment: I am glad that it helped. Please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/342523) and [upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/342523) if it is working